# homebrew ruby: gem command not found

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems, dockerfile, homebrew

Installing gem using rbenv in a dockerfile: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

These are the steps:

```
RUN brew install rbenv ruby-build
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init - bash)"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN rbenv install 3.2.2
RUN rbenv global 3.2.2
ENV PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin:$PATH"
```

But, when I try to run gem command it's giving **error: gem command not found**.

```
RUN gem install bundler
```

Comment: You don't usually need version managers like `rbenv` in a Docker image: the image only normally contains a single application and its runtime.  Can you build your image `FROM ruby:3.2.2` and skip this setup?

Comment: @DavidMaze I am using jenkins/inbound-agent as the base image. what's the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can install ruby and rubygems

```
FROM jenkins/inbound-agent:alpine

USER root
RUN apk --no-cache add curl ruby ruby-dev g++ make openssl

RUN gem install bundler
```